# Oracle Apex 18. some icon of the universal theme are missing

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

i'm using oracle apex 18.1.
Some of the icons of the universal themes are missing while i'm trying to use them.

For example, for a button, the fa-bomb is present but the fa-workflow or fa-taks-alt are missing.

I can't figure why some icons works and some don't.
I can't see either where the icons files are located or a list of all icons available to me. Looks like the majority is there, but the one's missing are the one I need. :)

Anyone already had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up Developer tools in your browser (F12 in Chrome or Firefox), go to the network tab, press Control + F5 for a hard refresh, then filter for **font-apex**, you should be able to see the CSS file that contains the each of the font-apex icons that are supported. In my screenshot below, 2.2.1 is the font-apex version and 21.2.0 is my version of APEX.

[image: Network Requests]

If you navigate to that directory on your web server, there is also a non-minified version of the CSS file if you'd like to look at that.

[image: Folder]

If you wish to see all of the icons from within the APEX Page Designers, if you create a button on a page, then click on the List of Values button next to the Icon field, a popup will appear with all of the available icons for you to use.

[image: Page Designer Icons]

Another option is in your application, go to Utilities then Font Apex Icons for a full list of supported icons and an editor to apply modifiers and such. I'm not 100% sure if this existed in your version of APEX but it is available in the most recent version.

[image: Font Apex Icons]

Comment: Great, many thanks. it's just what I needed.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark the question as accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking list of available icons on [Oracle APEX Universal Theme](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/icons) site, then: it contains the most recent list of icons (for the last Apex version).

Your version (18.1) is 4 *generations* old and it is possible that it doesn't contain all icons available in 21.2.

What to do? Upgrade; there's nothing else you could do (at least, I don't know what you *could* do).